# Custom Execution Strategy With Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a .Net Core 3.1 Windows Service running using EF Core with a custom `ExecutionStrategy`.  This strategy has some logic in `ShouldRetryOn()` to perform time based logging when exceptions occur.  It is working well form the perspective of issuing the warnings when I want them.

What I would like to know is if there is a way from within the `ExecutionStrategy` to know if the retry attempt succeeds.  Let's assume I have a `MaxRetryCount` of 10, but after 3 retries it was successful, I would like to know about the success.

I did look into the `Execute` and `ExcecuteAsync` methods but they are only called once so there doesn't seem to be a way to tie into them.  I didn't see anything else in the `ExecutionStrategy` that I could leverage to be notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a [related post on github](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27368) to the EF team.

> To know if the operation succeeded in general (with or without
> retries), you can override Execute and ExecuteAsync, call their base
> methods, and if those base methods haven't raised any exception, then
> the operation succeeded.